# how to update or query xml with xmlns attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xml-namespaces

say my xml doc is this

```
<root xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <parent prop="1">
  <child>
   <field name="1">
    <value1>abc</value1>
    <value2>cdf</value2>
   </field>
   <field name="2">
    <value1>efg</value1>
    <value2>hjk</value2>
   </field>
  </child>
 </parent>
 <parent2>
   <prop atrb="2">abc</prop>
 </parent2>
</root>
```

i have it a table newTable2 and xml datatyped column as xmlcol1

here is the query i worte

```
SELECT        xmlcol1.query('/root/parent/child/field/value1/text()') AS a
FROM            newTable2
```

this works when i remove the xmlns attribute if i put it back it does can anyone explain why is it so and how can i query for same keeping the xmlns attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind i found the answer
i just need to use the
    `;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance')`
before the query

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
;with xmlnamespaces (
    default 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
)
SELECT xmlcol1.query('/root/parent/child/field/value1/text()') AS a_query
    , xmlcol1.value('(/root/parent/child/field/value1/text())[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS a_value_1
    , xmlcol1.value('(/root/parent/child/field/value1/text())[2]', 'varchar(255)') AS a_value_2
FROM newTable2
```

Comment: thnx
bdw what are the numbers in [] signify?

Comment: [1] says to take exactly first text value among all text values of nodes `value1`. In your document it is `'abc'`.
[2] says to take exactly second text value among all text values of nodes `value1`. In your document it is `'efg'`.

Comment: Where do you update it? You just select. For example, you have an xml document as you mentioned above. What other xml document would you like to get after update?

Comment: it would be great if you could take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22643699/how-to-update-multiple-xml-node-values-through-a-single-query