# how to update multiple xml node values through a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

consider the xml

```
<root>
  <parent id="1">
    <child>
      <field name="1">
        <value>abc</value>
      </field>
      <field name="2">
        <value>cdf</value>
      </field>
      <field name="2">
        <value>xyz</value>
      </field>
      <field name="1">
         <value>uvw</value>
      </field>
    </child>
  </parent>
  <parent id="2">
    <child>
      <field name="1">
        <value>123</value>
      </field>
      <field name="3">
        <value>234</value>
      </field>
      <field name="4">
        <value>34</value>
      </field>
      <field name="1">
        <value>544</value>
      </field>
   </child>
 </parent>
```

i want to update the text value of 'value' where 'name' attribute of field node is equal to '1'

here is what i have right now....

```
update newTable
set xmlcol.modify('replace value of(/root/parent/child/field[@name="1"]/value/text()) with "newValue"')
```

will this work for all occurrence or just first one???

Comment: Did you try to test it?

Comment: i was doing it earlier but could not get the result right now i am on the run so cant test it straight away

Answer (score 1):

for anyone this worked for me.....

```
BEGIN

declare @I int

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'your namespace')

SELECT @I= xmlcol.value('count(/root/parent/child/field[@name="1"]/value/)', 'int')

FROM newTable

select @I as a

while @I > 0 

  begin

  ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'your namespace')

  update newTable set xmlcol.modify('replace value of (/root/parent/child/field[@name="1"]/value/text()) with "newValue"')

  set @I = @I - 1

end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work only for the first (second or whatever @i is) occurrence.

```
declare @i int = 1;

update newTable
set xmlcol.modify('replace value of (/root/parent/child/field[@name="1"]/value/text())[{sql:variable("@i")}] with "newValue"');
```

You should replace all the values with the new ones in a loop.